# N1ql Couchbase: How to get child with N1qlQueryResult?

Tags: java, couchbase, nosql

This might be more of a general querying question as I'm fairly new to databases.

If I have this document in a couchbase bucket:

```
{
  "accId": "1234",
  "operation": "test",
  "response": "a response"
}
```

I can get the response with the code

```
N1qlQueryResult result = bucket.query(select("response").fromCurrentBucket().where((x("accId").eq("\""+Id+"\"")).and(x("operation").eq("\""+op+"\""))));
```

But if my JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "organization": {
    "accId": "1234",
    "operation": "test",
    "response": "a response
  }
}
```

How would I go about getting the response?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couchbase stores JSON document. So it will be fetched as mentioned as below mentioned query.

```
select * from bucketName where organization.accId="1234" and organization.operation="test"
```